# Base64 encoded images with Sharepoint 2010 deployments

Tags: 2010, content-deployment

I'm currently using sharepoint 2010 and I want to use base64 encoded images. They work fine on our development server, but when the server goes through the standard content-deployment process to our live server, the data uris get truncated. This seems like it might be getting caught in sharepoint's url limits.

Does anyone have any unique and/or preferably easy methods they have used to solve this problem and be able to use encoded images?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this might help. Seems like IE 8 has some limitations on Base64 encoded images.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159500/internet-explorer-and-base64-image-display

Comment: Yeah, sadly that's not the case. I already had a fallback for IE8 and less. The problem is the images are being truncated down to 255 characters on the server and so it's not working on any browser.

Comment: How are you storing the Base64 string? and I'm also curious to why your using Base64 strings for images?

Comment: In css as background images for a few layout images/icons. It's a bit of a performance boost for small images as you don't need a separate request for them.

Comment: Doesn't sound like the small gain you will receive is worth the trouble your having trying to implement it in SharePoint (I think it's a SharePoint issue). I think you should look at CSS Image sprites instead. Then you have 1 request for the image file and it can be cached so it's only for the first visit to the site.

Comment: I actually use both methods. One of the main images I have encoded is about 7 icons in a single sprite that comes out to <5kb. I then encoded the sprite into my css for maximum performance. Unfortunately it does seem like encoding the image isn't going to work though.